# AWS Cognito alternatives to set/comunicate session to different domains using cookies or callbacks or any aws cognito endpoint

Tags: session, cookies, single-sign-on, subdomain, amazon-cognito

currently, I'm working on an application in which we want to offer a single sign-on experience, but let me put you in the context:

We have two different Cognito clients created for the same Cognito pool, both are configured to allow the users to login into two different applications:

- App A: mydomain.com
- App B: appb.mydomain.com

well, the thing is that when a user uses the hosted UI to log in to the first application,  I noticed that the Cognito server creates a cookie called "Cognito" as can see in the image:
[Cookie set by the auth server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86X6W.png)

Then, when a user tries to access the other application appb.mydomain.com, and the application,  instead of showing the hosted UI, the user automatically enters the application without going to all the login process again, and this is possible because of the cookie I mentioned (when I delete that cookie, then the user is requested to login again using its credentials).

So, that's nice because the user doesn't need to go through all the login process again. But my situation is the following:
I want to create a login page in mydomain.com with my own customized form and using the Cognito SDK. I already have the backend working, also the frontend. The backend can authenticate users to get the JWT tokens (IDtoken, refresh token, etc.) as you can see in the next image:
[Tokens I get when I authenticate a user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9tlN.png)

But at this point I'm not able to redirect the user to appb.mydomain.com with a valid session, I mean, I have the JWT tokens, and I tried to do the same thing that the hosted UI clients are doing, that is setting a cookie somehow containing the JWT session. But I don't know how to make the application appb.mydomain.com  to be able to detect this cookie. But the most important problem is that I really don't know how to construct a valid cookie (like Cognito's) to be detected by mydomain.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com (this domain is shared for both Hosted UI clients).

I don't know if this approach is feasible, or if there is another approach to send a JWT token to the auth server with a callback to redirect the user to the appb.mydomain.com
without going to all the login process again or something like that.

Do you have any advice on how to implement this kind of SSO Experience? I'm using .Net Core in the backend.

Comment: Just FYI - you're not asking one question here but rather want to start a discussion. Storing cookies is trivial in almost any programming language. You could store your JWT there (with some security considerations, of course). You would need to narrow down the question so that is's actually answerable.